# VGA splitter (2 VGAs,1 monitor)

Tags: desktop, vga, splitter, multiple-desktop

Is there a way I can use a VGA splitter to connect one monitor to two desktops and switch between the two when I need to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option for what you could use is called a [KVM switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch).

These are used to connect 2 or more computers, using one **K**eyboard, **V**ideo (output) and **M**ouse, with either a physical switch, or software switching capacity, depending on the device. Of course, whether you use the Keyboard and Mouse functionality is up to you, and you could have dedicated peripherals connected instead. Some of these also have capability to swap other USB devices, as well as audio devices.

These are commonly used for administrating servers, where you're likely to have several machines in one place.

Naturally, these switches could exist as purely video switches, with a physical switch/dial to choose where to output the video to.

Comment: Great,a KVM switch is exactly what I need.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you need a monitor with DVI and VGA inputs. VGA is normally a blue colour and DVI is normally white.

[image]

You connect one computer with the VGA cable and the other to the DVI port using either the DVI port if there is one, or a DVI to VGA converter which costs very little.

[image]

Make sure that the monitor you pick has an easy way to switch between DVI input and VGA input. Some are not simple to switch. You just need a small button on the front or sides that quickly switches between the two.

The best ones have an independent button that will switch between the two.

Comment: Thanks.My monitor has 1 input,which is VGA.Is there a splitter with 2 VGA inputs and 1 VGA output to the monitor,plus a switch to change between PC1 and PC2?

Comment: That would work fine - possibly cheaper to get a secondhand monitor with two inputs though. Amazon have a switch, but they can be found cheaper elsewhere. http://bit.ly/vgaswitch - you will need an extra VGA cable too.